# Why is the react-map-gl Source not using an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, mapbox, react-map-gl

I'm trying to add geoJSON into a react-map-gl map using typescript

here is my code

```
<Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={data}>
    <Layer {...layerStyles}/>
</Source>
```

the `data` variable is a parsed JSON file so it is an object not

the error I get is

```
 Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SourceProps | Readonly<SourceProps>): Source', gave the following error.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string | Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | undefined'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>': type, features
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SourceProps, context: any): Source', gave the following error.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string | Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | undefined'.  TS2769

    123 |             onViewportChange={(nextView:typeof viewport) => setViewport(nextView)}>
    124 |                 {/* GeoJSON */}
  > 125 |                 <Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={data}>
        |                                                     ^
    126 |                  <Layer {...layerStyles}/>
    127 |                 </Source> 
    128 |                 {markers}
```

And the type of the data props in the Source component is supposed to be an object as you can see from the documentation https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/source

if you need any more information please ask

Comment: What is `data` in this context?

Comment: it's a JSON file that contained all the geoJSON I imported then parsed into an object, do it's an object containing the geoJSON

Comment: Have you verified that the shape is correct when it reaches this code? Clearly the `Source` component disagrees and believes that `data` is missing properties named `type` and `features`.

Comment: Yes, data has both a type and features I can console.log both those.

Comment: Can you share those here?

Comment: type = ```FeatureCollection```, features return ```0: {type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
1: {type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
2: {type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
3: {type: 'Feature', properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}```
... up to 23

Comment: each feature contains ```geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: Array(2)}
properties: {OBJECTID: 1, HASTUS: 317581, TRANSLINK_ID: 306654, DESCRIPTION: 'Dockside ferry terminal', STREETNAME: 'Ferry St', …}
type: "Feature"```

Comment: Can you show how you are importing the JSON? Are you assigning it a type when you import it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation

Let's pull apart this error:

```
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SourceProps | Readonly<SourceProps>): Source'
...
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SourceProps, context: any): Source
```

At the top level it is showing the two possible ways that you can use the `Source` component. Assuming you aren't assigning it a `context`, let's continue looking at Overload 1

```
Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string | Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> | undefined'.
```

This is telling us that typescript thinks `data` is an `object`, but it's expecting it to be specifically a `string` or a `Feature` or a `FeatureCollection` (specifically features of `Geometry, GeoJsonProperties`)
This tells us that `object` is not a specific enough type to satisfy the compiler.

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>': type, features
```

Here's it's trying to be helpful by telling us what's missing in the `object` type. Note that it's reduced your type to an empty object without properties.

#### Solution

So how do you tell the compiler what `data` is?
I'm going to assume that you are fetching the data and so typescript is unable to infer it's type automatically

Option 1 - use a type guard to check the incoming data

```
function isFeatureCollection(data: unknown): data is FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> {
    return (
        typeof data === 'object'
        && data !== null
        && 'type' in data
        && 'features' in data
    );
}
```

Then use the type guard to exit out of the render, and typescript will know that after this check that `data` will be the type expected by `Source`

```
if (!isFeatureCollection(data)) return null;

<Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={data}>
    <Layer {...layerStyles}/>
</Source>
```

Option 2 - Cast the type using `as` to what you expect it to be:

```
const data = await getData() as FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>;
```

This isn't recommended as you're throwing away Typescript's type guarantee here